# Prove that if and q are two distinct prime numbers, then ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are two distinct positive prime numbers, then $log_p(q)$ is irrational.

I think first we have to assume $log_p(q)$  is rational.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\log_p q = \frac a b \iff p^{a/b} = q \iff p^a = q^b$$